# How to map postgresql custom enum column with Slick2.0.1?

Tags: scala, enums, postgresql-9.2, slick-2.0

I just can't figure it out. What I am using right now is:

```
abstract class DBEnumString extends Enumeration {
  implicit val enumMapper = MappedJdbcType.base[Value, String](
     _.toString(),
     s => this.withName(s)
  )
}
```

And then:

```
object SomeEnum extends DBEnumString {
  type T = Value
  val A1 = Value("A1")
  val A2 = Value("A2")
}
```

The problem is, during insert/update JDBC driver for PostgreSQL complains about parameter type being "character varying" when column type is "some_enum", which is reasonable as I am converting SomeEnum to String.

How do I tell Slick to treat String as DB-defined "enum_type"? Or how to define some other Scala-type that will map to "enum_type"?

Comment: I don't know if this would solve your problem, but have you seen [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg)?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not mention enumerations. Anyway - Thanks. I will reach to the author of this library.

Comment: Side note: It is more idiomatic in Scala to use a `trait SomeEnum` with `case object A1`, etc. children, instead of Enumeration.

Comment: Plus, please provide the exact error message you getting and the exact line of code that produces it.

Comment: Crosslink: https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/scalaquery/fe61e9f7-5ddd-429b-9909-a3645ff63f90%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

Answer (score 7):

I had similar confusion when trying to get my postgreSQL enums to work with slick. [Slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) allows you to use Scala enums with your databases enums, and the test suite shows [how](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/PgEnumSupportSuite.scala).

Below is an example.

Say we have this enumerated type in our database.

```
CREATE TYPE Dog AS ENUM ('Poodle', 'Labrador');
```

We want to be able to map these to Scala enums, so we can use them happily with Slick. We can do this with slick-pg, an extension for slick.

First off, we make a Scala version of the above enum.

```
object Dogs extends Enumeration {
  type Dog = Value
  val Poodle, Labrador = Value
}
```

To get the extra functionality from slick-pg we extend the normal PostgresDriver and say we want to map our Scala enum to the PostgreSQL one (remember to change the slick driver in application.conf to the one you've created).

```
object MyPostgresDriver extends PostgresDriver with PgEnumSupport {
  override val api = new API with MyEnumImplicits {}

  trait MyEnumImplicits {
    implicit val dogTypeMapper = createEnumJdbcType("Dog", Dogs)
    implicit val dogListTypeMapper = createEnumListJdbcType("Dog", Dogs)

    implicit val dogColumnExtensionMethodsBuilder = createEnumColumnExtensionMethodsBuilder(Dogs)
    implicit val dogOptionColumnExtensionMethodsBuilder = createEnumOptionColumnExtensionMethodsBuilder(Dogs)
  }
}
```

Now when you want to make a new model case class, simply use the corresponding Scala enum.

```
case class User(favouriteDog: Dog)
```

And when you do the whole DAO table shenanigans, again you can just use it.

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "User") {
  def favouriteDog = column[Dog]("favouriteDog")
  def * = (favouriteDog) <> (Dog.tupled, Dog.unapply _)
}
```

Obviously you need the Scala Dog enum in scope wherever you use it.

Due to a [bug in slick](https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1152), currently you can't dynamically link to a custom slick driver in `application.conf` (it should work). This means you either need to run play framework with start and not get dynamic recompiling, or you can create a standalone sbt project with just the custom slick driver in it and depend on it locally.

Comment: Can you include any of the relevant content from the link here in case the link goes bad?